# Change boot partition to another disk

Tags: linux, boot, partition, dual-boot, disk

So I installed dual boot fedora and win10 weeks ago. Booting to win10 almost take no time but booting to fedora takes about 1.5 minute (I already checked with systemd-analyze and disabled some services).

Then I noticed that my /boot partition is in HDD sda5, is there anyway to change/move it to my SSD(nvme)? I expect it increase my boot time.[image: lsblk]

Comment: As soon as the bootloader has successfully loaded the kernel and initramfs files to RAM, the job of the `/boot` partition is done. You could even omit it entirely from `/etc/fstab` and it usually would not have any effect to the boot process (you would then have to mount it manually before installing any kernel updates, so it would be inconvenient). Unless you experience a significant delay in loading GRUB or before Fedora's boot splash screen appears after selecting Fedora from the GRUB menu, the `/boot` partition is unlikely to be the cause of the slow boot.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Also: which partition is your root filesystem on?   as @telcoM says, /boot is tiny and used only to load grub and the kernel - Fedora itself is on /.  if / is on your NVME drive and your boot is slow, then disk speed is not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a "Fast Startup" option which is essentially a Hibernation: it retains a bunch of system settings (like partition superblocks) that reduce the workload during boot and make it much faster.

Unfortunately, that means other OS (such as Linux) detect inconsistencies in file systems at boot time, and have to reconstruct the superblocks and other things. Effectively, Win10 makes itself look good by bypassing a clean shutdown, which then sabotages Fedora.

https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode